# Silverlight Website browser zoom issue

Tags: asp.net, css, silverlight-4.0, cross-browser

I have developed a Silverlight website. The problem i am facing currently is when i use the browser zoom, it displays the magnified version of the site without browser scrollbars. The content is clipped.
Please check these images which displays my problem.

http://demo.digi-corp.com/withzoom.jpg

http://demo.digi-corp.com/withoutzoom.jpg

The following is the design code in my aspx page where the silverlight object is hosted.

<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost" style="background: #9EEE69;">
        <object id="silverlightObject" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
            width="100%" height="100%">

```
    html, body
    {
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    body
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #silverlightControlHost
    {
        height: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create javascript function

function bodyLoadEvent() 
{

 this.form1.style.height = (parseInt(document.body.offsetHeight) - 5).toString()  + "px";

this.form1.style.width = (parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth) - 5).toString() + "px";

document.getElementById("myhtmlbody").style.height = (parseInt(document.body.offsetHeight) - 5).toString() + "px";

document.getElementById("myhtmlbody").style.width= (parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth) - 5).toString() + "px";

}

and call this function on body load.
i.e. 

 <body onload="bodyLoadEvent();">

     <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%;">

  .......

 </form>

 </body>

Comment: Sometimes it creates issue in chrome it display scroll bar at 100% too, if it occurs in your application then do not set width for form and body, and apply style for both as 100%.

Answer (score 1):

@brijesh; you have to define `min-width` in your `body` tag like this:

```
body
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        min-width:1000px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks That works fine when I zoom in the browser. But when i reset the browser zoom it takes the min-width parameter into account and does not fit into browser

Comment: 'does not fit into browser' what you want to say can you explain it more. Thanks

Comment: ya sure. when i reset the zoom as 100% and view it in 1024*768 it will display the scrollbar as the minimum width is provided as 1000 px. So what i want to do is when the zoom is set to 100% that is the default value it should fit into browser without scrollbar.

Comment: it's just an example you can set your min-width your self like 980px.

Comment: But this site can be viewd on any pc of any resolution. Then how can I manage my min-width as per the resolution ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4235/discussion-between-sandeep-and-brijesh-patel)